# Nodes and fragids data structre

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Does the `nodes` and `fragids` of the viewer represent a directed graph data structure?

If so, how is an edge represented?

What does an edge between two nodes represent?

Does it always represent a tree or there could be more than one connected component?

Is there a visual example map between the integer array to the graph it represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the essence of your question? What are you trying to achieve? The nodes and fragments are being crunched in an array to save memory when dealing with large models with an important number of components. The viewer API exposes methods that lets you iterate through the children of a node given a nodeId or its fragments:

-instanceTree.enumNodeChildren

-instanceTree.enumNodeFragments

```
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

var rootId = this.rootId = instanceTree.getRootId();
var rootName = instanceTree.getNodeName(rootId);
var childCount = 0;

instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(rootId, function(childId) {

   var childName = instanceTree.getNodeName(childId);

   console.log(childName);

   childCount++;
});
```

Starting from the root node, you can build the kind of data structure you want. [This article](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/03/breaking-change-in-accessing-model-instance-tree-with-view-data-api.html) I wrote may be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to find ways to search faster, for example, to find the closest nodes by the distance to a certain node or to a position, I need a BFS for that.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes represent an object, which seats into a tree hierarchy representing the data structure in the original design model. For example, if you send an Inventor file to Model Derivative, each node will represent an assembly, a sub-assembly or a part. The tree instance will link the nodes together to reflect that structure.
fragmentIds represent meshes. A particular object might be a collection of fragments. For example an object has an id (unique id which maps to the original design model unique ID or GUID), each object might have geometry which is a collection of fragments.
In the Forge model, and in the Forge viewerAPI, geometry is represented as mesh with triangles. So unlike in a Brep representation, there is no surface edge, but only triangles edge. The silhouette shows on screen because the WEBGL renderer renders the meshes in the canvas, but it is not an edge per the Brep definition. If you are talking about triangle edges which are there to define the mesh, then it is another story.
However, the Forge Model Derivative API can export your model to STEP, IGES, STL format where you will eventually get a Brep representation.
To see the nodes, display the object tree from the Viewer (or metadata from the json response), and to see the meshes (collection of fragmentIds), isolate a node.

Comment: So what is the data structure of the nodes? It's an array but does it has an underlying structure like a heap or a binary tree? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays